# Integration Tests for WebAPI and transactions

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, transactions

I have a **client facing ASP.NET Web API** which has both direct SQL server calls as well as calling **other** ASP.NET Web APIs to do data operations. I want to do an end to end integration test of the **client REST API** to test the routes of the other called REST APIs as well as various data operations are successful.

The tests that I want to do are (1) the routes for different REST APIs are correct and (2) adding and updating a customer through the REST API is successful. Simply testing a customer is added can make sure the routes are correct as well as the data operation is successful.

I want to rollback the transaction after completing the tests. For example, during the test, a new customer is created through a REST API like http://localhost/Customer/POST and at the end of the tests, the user is deleted.

Is transactional operation possible for REST API and any suggestion for Integration tests are welcome. I'm using NUNIT in Visual Studio 2013 environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the current options are not ideal, here is what I have set-up on a relatively large project - which is not far away from the official testing guide over [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-with-aspnet-web-api) . This all relies on automation of your build/test/deploy processes (i.e. ALM- application life-cycle management, we use Visual Studio Release Manager 2013)

1). On the CI server we run a bunch of unit tests on every checkin that perform some basic tests by instantiating the controller class directly and calling the get/put/post/delete methods like we would with any other unit test. These use mocked backend (no database connectivity) layers, so I can test the API, Data, Business layers all independently of each other.

2). On the nightly automated deployment to the "integration" environment we run the above checks again on each layer of the project individually, and then deploy all assets to the Integration server. Once deployed, we then run some build conformation checks that use the "ASP.net Web API Client Library" (look for them on nuget and asp.net web site) to perform real end to end tests from a "client" all the way through every layer to the db, at the end of the unit test after some asserts we run a simple delete query to roll back the data. Unfortunately there is not a concept of "Transactions" in webapi at present, you have to create your own. To separate unit test from build conformation / acceptance tests, we have a custom action filter on the unit tests that allow us to exclude given tests. So our conformation tests look like this:

```
[Test, ConformationTest]
Public void TestGetCustomer(){
   //build get request here
}
```

3). The build then moves through a formal test stage (manual merge across branches) before being deployed to LIVE, because we use a release pipeline ("Visual Studio Release manager 2013") we know the builds between environments are identical, hence we only do a handful of GET requests on live deployment to make sure the API is running before re-enabling the server on the load balancer.

The reason we do this is that Web API needs to be hosted somewhere to test it end to end, the unit test catch most errors immediately on check-in - and the nightly anything route related as spinning up a VM on every checkin is expensive if you have several devs checking in regularly all day. This does cover most aspects, but as I said not 100% ideal.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you could do it.

By adding the current transaction to the TestServer. When an request is sent to the TestServer. You can set the transaction as current to enable Transaction Flow between UnitTest and TestServer.

```
using (var server = TestServer.Create(app =>
        {

            app.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Transaction", Transaction.Current));

            app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
              if (app.Properties.ContainsKey("Transaction"))
                {
                    Transaction.Current = (Transaction)app.Properties["Transaction"];
                }

                var invoke = next.Invoke();

                if (app.Properties.ContainsKey("Transaction"))
                {
                    Transaction.Current = null;
                }

                return invoke;
            });

        }))
        {
          //Your test code
        });
```

Comment: Se update above. You need to cleanup Transaction.Current. Else the thread gets dirty.